# qt pyside - qsql*model, qabstractitemmodel and qtreeview interaction

Tags: python, model-view-controller, qt, sqlite, pyside

I want to produce a simple enough application which uses a QTreeView widget to show hierarchical data from a SQLite3 (flat) table, use QDataWidgetMapper to populate some lineedit fields, allow user to edit, which in turn updates the table.  Simple & basic (for most!).

I have been working on the basis that the following process would be the best way of doing this:

1. Connect to Dbase
2. Query data
3. Create and populate custom QAbstractItemModel from the data (manipulating it through a `dict` to create nodes, parents and children dynamically - for each dict entry a 'node' is generated with an associated parent)
4. Use QDatawidgetmapper to populate other widgets
5. User edits data
6. QAbstractItemModel (QAIM) is updated
7. Then have to run an UPDATE, INSERT or whatever query using new values in the QAIM model.
8. Refresh the QAIM and associated widgets.

I realise if I were just using a QTableView or QListView I would not need the custom model and could just write straight back into the database. The process I have outlined above seems to mean having to keep two sets of data going - i.e. the SQLite table and the custom QAIM and ensure that they are both kept up to date. This seems a bit cumbersome to me and I'm sure there must be a better way of doing it where the QTreeView is taking its data straight from the SQLite table - with the obvious need for some manipulation to convert the flat data into hierarchical data.

I am wondering, of course, whether I have completely misunderstood the relationship between QAbstractItemModel and the QSQL*Models and I *am* overcomplicating it through ignorance?

Thanks

Comment: what format have your hierarchical data? i usually use headers and lines (invoices for example) but they use a model every one.

Comment: for (relative) simplicity I am currently just using a single table with a 'parent' column.  This indicates which node/record the child should be appended to.

Comment: well without take a look at the concrete data i can't say for sure you should store it in other way but the chances that store parents and childs in the same table would be a good idea are small, i have one case in production though, anyway i think you will have to stick with your idea of maintain your model and SQL in sync, Qt don't have to begin with a perfect support for editing SQL tables, i have created a QSqlQueryModel subclass to have a better QSqlTableModel, maybe you could do the same too, but if you only are going to use one time, i don't recommend you to do it, would much more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a proxy model that acts as a bridge between `QSql*Model` and the view. For that, you need to subclass `QAbstractProxyModel`. You have to have a consistent way of finding parent-child relationships in proxy model and mapping them to the source model, so that might require keeping some tally in the proxy model.

When you are sub-classing `QAbstractProxyModel`, you need to re-define, at minimum, these methods:

- rowCount
- columnCount
- parent
- index
- data
- mapToSource
- mapFromSource

Also, keep in mind that `QAbstractProxyModel` does not auto-propagate signals through. So, in order to have the view be aware of changes in source model (like insert, delete, update), you need to pass them in the proxy model (while of course, updating your mappings in the proxy model).

It will require some work, but in the end you'll have a more flexible structure. And it will eliminate all the stuff that you need to do for synchronizing database and custom `QAbstractItemModel`.

**Edit**

A custom proxy model that groups items from a flat model according to a given column:

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple
import random

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

groupItem = namedtuple("groupItem",["name","children","index"])
rowItem = namedtuple("rowItem",["groupIndex","random"])


class GrouperProxyModel(QtGui.QAbstractProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GrouperProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self._rootItem = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        self._groups = []       # list of groupItems
        self._groupMap = {}     # map of group names to group indexes
        self._groupIndexes = [] # list of groupIndexes for locating group row
        self._sourceRows = []   # map of source rows to group index
        self._groupColumn = 0   # grouping column.

    def setSourceModel(self, source, groupColumn=0):
        super(GrouperProxyModel, self).setSourceModel(source)

        # connect signals
        self.sourceModel().columnsAboutToBeInserted.connect(self.columnsAboutToBeInserted.emit)
        self.sourceModel().columnsInserted.connect(self.columnsInserted.emit)
        self.sourceModel().columnsAboutToBeRemoved.connect(self.columnsAboutToBeRemoved.emit)
        self.sourceModel().columnsRemoved.connect(self.columnsRemoved.emit)

        self.sourceModel().rowsInserted.connect(self._rowsInserted)
        self.sourceModel().rowsRemoved.connect(self._rowsRemoved)
        self.sourceModel().dataChanged.connect(self._dataChanged)

        # set grouping
        self.groupBy(groupColumn)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent == self._rootItem:
            # root level
            return len(self._groups)
        elif parent.internalPointer() == self._rootItem:
            # children level
            return len(self._groups[parent.row()].children)
        else:
            return 0

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        if self.sourceModel():
            return self.sourceModel().columnCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())
        else:
            return 0

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if parent == self._rootItem:
            # this is a group
            return self.createIndex(row,column,self._rootItem)
        elif parent.internalPointer() == self._rootItem:
            return self.createIndex(row,column,self._groups[parent.row()].index)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        parent =  index.internalPointer()
        if parent == self._rootItem:
            return self._rootItem
        else:
            parentRow = self._getGroupRow(parent)
            return self.createIndex(parentRow,0,self._rootItem)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            parent = index.internalPointer()
            if parent == self._rootItem:
                return self._groups[index.row()].name
            else:
                parentRow = self._getGroupRow(parent)
                sourceRow = self._sourceRows.index(self._groups[parentRow].children[index.row()])
                sourceIndex = self.createIndex(sourceRow, index.column(), 0)
                return self.sourceModel().data(sourceIndex, role)
        return None

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        return self.sourceModel().headerData(section, orientation, role)

    def mapToSource(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        parent = index.internalPointer()
        if not parent.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        elif parent == self._rootItem:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        else:
            rowItem_ = self._groups[parent.row()].children[index.row()]
            sourceRow = self._sourceRows.index(rowItem_)
            return self.createIndex(sourceRow, index.column(), QtCore.QModelIndex())

    def mapFromSource(self, index):
        rowItem_ = self._sourceRows[index.row()]
        groupRow = self._getGroupRow(rowItem_.groupIndex)
        itemRow = self._groups[groupRow].children.index(rowItem_)
        return self.createIndex(itemRow,index.column(),self._groupIndexes[groupRow])

    def _clearGroups(self):
        self._groupMap = {}
        self._groups = []
        self._sourceRows = []

    def groupBy(self,column=0):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._clearGroups()
        self._groupColumn = column
        sourceModel = self.sourceModel()
        for row in range(sourceModel.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())):
            groupName = sourceModel.data(self.createIndex(row,column,0),
                                         QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

            groupIndex = self._getGroupIndex(groupName)
            rowItem_ = rowItem(groupIndex,random.random())
            self._groups[groupIndex.row()].children.append(rowItem_)
            self._sourceRows.append(rowItem_)

        self.endResetModel()

    def _getGroupIndex(self, groupName):
        """ return the index for a group denoted with name.
        if there is no group with given name, create and then return"""
        if groupName in self._groupMap:
            return self._groupMap[groupName]
        else:
            groupRow = len(self._groupMap)
            groupIndex = self.createIndex(groupRow,0,self._rootItem)
            self._groupMap[groupName] = groupIndex
            self._groups.append(groupItem(groupName,[],groupIndex))
            self._groupIndexes.append(groupIndex)
            self.layoutChanged.emit()
            return groupIndex

    def _getGroupRow(self, groupIndex):
        for i,x in enumerate(self._groupIndexes):
            if id(groupIndex)==id(x):
                return i
        return 0

    def _rowsInserted(self, parent, start, end):
        for row in range(start, end+1):
            groupName = self.sourceModel().data(self.createIndex(row,self._groupColumn,0),
                                                QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            groupIndex = self._getGroupIndex(groupName)
            self._getGroupRow(groupIndex)
            groupItem_ = self._groups[self._getGroupRow(groupIndex)]
            rowItem_ = rowItem(groupIndex,random.random())
            groupItem_.children.append(rowItem_)
            self._sourceRows.insert(row, rowItem_)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def _rowsRemoved(self, parent, start, end):
        for row in range(start, end+1):
            rowItem_ = self._sourceRows[start]
            groupIndex = rowItem_.groupIndex
            groupItem_ = self._groups[self._getGroupRow(groupIndex)]
            childrenRow = groupItem_.children.index(rowItem_)
            groupItem_.children.pop(childrenRow)
            self._sourceRows.pop(start)
            if not len(groupItem_.children):
                # remove the group
                groupRow = self._getGroupRow(groupIndex)
                groupName = self._groups[groupRow].name
                self._groups.pop(groupRow)
                self._groupIndexes.pop(groupRow)
                del self._groupMap[groupName]
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def _dataChanged(self, topLeft, bottomRight):
        topRow = topLeft.row()
        bottomRow = bottomRight.row()
        sourceModel = self.sourceModel()
        # loop through all the changed data
        for row in range(topRow,bottomRow+1):
            oldGroupIndex = self._sourceRows[row].groupIndex
            oldGroupItem = self._groups[self._getGroupRow(oldGroupIndex)]
            newGroupName = sourceModel.data(self.createIndex(row,self._groupColumn,0),QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            if newGroupName != oldGroupItem.name:
                # move to new group...
                newGroupIndex = self._getGroupIndex(newGroupName)
                newGroupItem = self._groups[self._getGroupRow(newGroupIndex)]

                rowItem_ = self._sourceRows[row]
                newGroupItem.children.append(rowItem_)

                # delete from old group
                oldGroupItem.children.remove(rowItem_)
                if not len(oldGroupItem.children):
                    # remove the group
                    groupRow = self._getGroupRow(oldGroupItem.index)
                    groupName = oldGroupItem.name
                    self._groups.pop(groupRow)
                    self._groupIndexes.pop(groupRow)
                    del self._groupMap[groupName]

        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've been doing a bit of research and was coming to the conclusion that QAbstractProxyModel might be the route.  It looks very complicated for me at the moment though :)

Comment: @StevenLee: Right now, I don't have a working example. Sorry. But I'm working on a custom proxy that groups items from a table model (like QSqlTableModel) based on a given column. If you like, I can share it when I'm done.

Comment: That would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: yeah this can be a good way to get what you want, i don't have used never a proxy for hierarchical data but it is flexible in what lets you to do indeed.

Comment: @StevenLee: I included my custom proxy that groups items from a flat model. Sorry for the delay, I hardly had time to finish this. To be honest, this might be a bit crude and possibly it could use some clean-up but for now it works as expected. It might give you some ideas.